# asp.net unique session when duplicate tab in IE

Tags: asp.net, session

I know this question has been asked before but I have not found a complete answer. When the user selects duplicate tab in IE it appears the current tab gets its url(with cookless session id) from the current window. Then the two tabs are sharing session values.

I have tried checking the referrer for null, but on the Duplicate Tab command in IE that value is set to the current tab.

The only workaround I see is to get rid of session.

Comment: I believe that is the big downfall of the cookieless sessions.

Comment: Yes. But with cookie sessions you also get a duplicated session on File, New Tab among other places.

Comment: Oh, i see you said Duplicate Tab, thought it said new tab. Yes, it's going to share the session whether cookieless or normal, in that case. If the Referrer is itself, or same as the new Tab, and the page is not a postback, couldn't you use that to say that this is likely a new tab?

Comment: Yes, but you have the same results on the condition where the user presses F5 or refresh.

Answer (score 2):

The last tab gets the latest session info, sessions are based on browser instances, not tabs, that is ust how they work.  You are fighting a losing battle.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the same site to two different domains. When your users want to open a second session, they can access the second domain, which will create a second session.